# Is ADAL JS supported on-premise ADFS 2016?

Tags: adal.js

I am trying to use ADAL JS for the on-premise Adfs 2016 for Implicit flow. Is it supported?

Can you please clarify?

Please let me know if there are any sample available for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ADAL JS suppots the ADFS 2016( refer [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/222)).  And since this library is developed for the single page applications which use the implicit flow, based on my understanding, it should also work for the implicit flow for ADFS 2016.